# if: Expression syntax Error in csh - not to accept other string than the only string it must accept

Tags: string, unix, if-statement, logical-operators, csh

There's this daemon with, for ex. 5 types in one script. Now, i want to be able to start/stop it by **specifying the number of the daemon(to start one by one), OR specify "all" (to start in bulk).** 

**The format:** (runscript) (commandName) (daemon # or "all") 
Need to satisfy **two conditions**, when the user inputs: 
(1) correctly *(either by number or "all)* OR 
(2) incorrectly *(either inputted num is greater than $count or all other string than "all").*
All conditions are already achieved except for one, if the user inputs **other** string than "all"

Sample code:

```
case 'startDaemon': #commandName
set count = 5

if ($#argv == 2 && $2 == all) then
    echo "correct, do this"
else if ($#argv == 2 && $2 < $count) then
    echo "correct too, do this"
else if ($#argv == 2 && ($2 != all || $2 >= $count)) then
    echo "Incorrect parameter: specify daemon # less than $count or 'all' to start all."
else 
    echo "Please use: $0(runscript) $1(commandname) (daemon # or all)"
```

whenever I type: ***(runscript) startDaemon hello***, for example, error shows:

```
if: Expression syntax
```

When it should have gone to the 3rd condition. Please help and kindly point out if the prob is in the conditions or logical operators or whatever. Thanks in advance

PS. Im using **csh**. The script given to me is in csh, so yep.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate problem is the comparison `$2 < $count`, which is invalid when `$count` contains a string.

Here is a working solution:

```
#!/bin/csh

set count = 5

if ($#argv == 2) then
    if ($2 == all) then
        echo "correct, do this"
    else if (`echo $2 | grep '^[0-9]*$'`) then
        if ($2 < $count) then
                echo "correct too, do this"
        else
           echo "Number must be less than 5"
        endif
    else
        echo "Incorrect parameter: specify daemon # less than $count or 'all' to start all."
    endif
else
    echo "Please use: $0(runscript) $1(commandname) (daemon # or all)"
endif
```